# PyQt5 Tab Widget: How can I get the index of active tab window on mouse click?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtabwidget

I have a Tab Widget with 2 Tabs. How can I get the index number of a Tab when I click on it?

```
self.tab = QTabWidget()
self.tab.addTab(self.widget1, "Tab1")
self.tab.addTab(self.widget2, "Tab2")

data_entry_tab.tabBarClicked.connect(self.OnTabClicked)

def OnTabClicked(self):
    tab_bar = self.sender()
    # I want to use idx to do some calculation
    idx = ?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`tabBarClicked`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtabwidget.html#tabBarClicked) signal:

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.tabwidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget()
        self.tabwidget.addTab(QtWidgets.QWidget(), "Tab1")
        self.tabwidget.addTab(QtWidgets.QWidget(), "Tab2")
        self.tabwidget.addTab(QtWidgets.QWidget(), "Tab3")

        self.setCentralWidget(self.tabwidget)

        self.tabwidget.tabBarClicked.connect(self.handle_tabbar_clicked)

    def handle_tabbar_clicked(self, index):
        print(index)

        print("x2:", index * 2)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks! Sorry I am new to this. How can I use 'index' as a variable?

Comment: @jabbarlee your question is confusing, what do you want to do with that index? It seems you have an XY problem

Comment: I want to use that signal tabBarClicked and grab index to use in another function. Like OnTabClick() with self.sender().

Comment: @jabbarlee your explanation is still confusing, if you provide a [mre] then maybe I could help you, otherwise I will continue on my way.

Comment: you have almost given answer. But in your code it prints index but  I wanna use it as a variable. Lets say I wanna multiply index by 2 not just print it.

Comment: @jabbarlee Your comment is not clear (it seems to me because you are a beginner), I will only respond when you provide the MRE, bye.

Answer (score 1):

whatever you have your Qtabwidget set up as, like lets say. `tabs = QTabWidget()`, for instance. then you would use `tabs.currentIndex()` to find the index of the tab that is currently open. so then you can be like `current_index = tabs.currentIndex()`, and use the index for whatever it is you were needing it for.